# Backbone replacing with html not working

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

In my backbone function, i have no.of filter methods, so i decided to instead using 'this.$el.append()', 'this.$el.html()' - but the replacing html() is not working. i thought i would be fine to repalce hole view with new collections.

as well it tried to make the this.$el.empty(), but not works... so how can i clear the existing element from the parent, and append the new generation elements..?

my code :

```
    renderBoard:function(item){
          var singleView = new taskListPhraseI.oneView({model:item}),
// after this, i need to make parent of the element should be empty...
          board = this.$el.append(singleView.render()),

          newBoard = board.find('.indBoard:last');
          this.positionBoards(newBoard);
        },
```

how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you have your view setup as follows

```
views = window.views || {};

views.ExampleView = Backbone.View.extend({

    initiliaze: function(){
        // do some stuff
    },

    render: function(){

        $(this.el).html("<YOUR HTML GOES HERE></YOUR HTML GOES HERE>");

        // return yourself as simple to chain access to your "el"
        return this;
    }

});
```

then when your rendering your view and want to remove all other views before hand, it'd go something like

```
renderView: function(item)
{
    var test=new views.ExampleView({
       model:item
    });

    // this should replace the elements contents with the views html above
    $(this.el).html(test.render().el);
}
```

If you're still having trouble, maybe 'this' has lost context, and no longer refers to your class, i'd debug what the value of that is when you are rendering.

Hope that helps